Lies, Damned Lies, and Statistics
I am measuring time of flight of an acoustic pulse over an arbitrary path length. How can I determine the statistical resolution of the device?
So, I collect a load of readings over a path length of (say) X and find standard deviation (SD) etc. Then I increase path length to 10X and the the SD looks amazing - yet the actual resolution remains the same.
What is the correct statistical measure to use that is time of flight independent?

If the resolution is a fixed amount regardless of total measurement then a statistical measure is pretty meaningless.

What device are you referring to? What does "amazing" mean numerically compared to the earlier test?

If you want to investigate standard deviation versus distance, and resolution versus distance, then you need to measure at more distances than two. Once you have readings at a sufficient number of distances, plot stddev and resolution versus distance, and look for trends, knees, flat bits, power laws. Then take some readings at the distances you didn't consider last time.

@Andyaka I mean, we obviously cannot use SD as a measure of how good our instrument is given the dependence of statistics on an arbitrary path length

@Finbarr It cannot be totally meaningless because because each measurement is slightly different and there is a spread

OK, maybe not totally meaningless, just not useful. You could quote a figure based on your measurements from, say 1 to 100m but someone using it only to measure distances from 1 to 10m would not achieve that figure. How would that be useful?

"the dependence of statistics on an arbitrary path length" - what does this phrase actually mean? that the statistical spread of actual readings varies with the choice of path length? the choice of words makes my head hurt, honestly.

Perhaps you could post a few of your measurements to be concrete?  Typically we normalise by dividing the sd by the mean.

You might want to consider accuracy as well as resolution and noise. How does the device handle the variation in speed of sound with air temperature and humidity?

@Andyaka That's all kept constant

I’m voting to close this question because it's about physics and math

Problem solved. The f/w is Relative Standard Deviation

@Neil_UK in comments gives some good advice.
For the very common SR04-type ultrasonic distance measurement, 40 kHz pulse frequency influences range. It causes "cogging" due to wavelength-in-air.
A high-resolution counter was used to measure time delay of 500 return pulses from a randomly-varying distance of the reflecting surface about 8.2cm away. I plotted the time-to-reflection, with the vertical scale representing the number of high-resolution counts from its clock (about 48 MHz?):
One could argue that resolution is only limited by the high-resolution clock period, but could equally argue that resolution is limited by 40 kHz transducer frequency representing one wavelength.
There may be another cogging source: that of the SR-04's own 4 MHz processor that is asynchronous when compared to an external timer started by us users.

To measure resolution you need at least two different distances, close to each other.  The smallest difference such that you can identify whether the two measurements differ (using whatever criteria you want) is your resolution.  If you put a p value on that, it's a statistical resolution.

Unfortunately I can only measure at one distance

@DirkBruere Then your system does not have a defined resolution, at least along the distance axis as you have no resolving power. Maybe you want to look at ranging accuracy? So true distance compared to measured distance?

@user1850479 Since I am resolving the time of flight to within a nanosecond finding true path length is a problem.

@DirkBruere Then you're testing accuracy rather than resolution.  When I worked in lidar we would put targets at precisely measured distances, measure with the device under test multiple times and compute the standard deviation of the error vs. distance for a plot

SD will be numerically the same if the resolution and noise are the same, no matter the distance being measured.
If the numerical value of SD is less at larger distances than at smaller distances, that is a real phenomenon and means that the sensor has higher noise at closer range.
Perhaps you’re comparing SD to the measured value? Sure, when the distance is small, SD is much larger relative to the value.

Then I increase path length to 10X and the the SD looks amazing

In your case, the context for SD would be the maximum value, ie. the maximum measurement range,   not to an arbitrary measured value (!).
And you probably need to take samples at various distances and plot SD vs distance just to see how and if the noise/resolution changes. Note that in stat-speak, a sample means a collection of measurements of a quantity. Usually a sample is more than one measurement, as opposed to the use of the word with regards to time-domain sampling in ADCs etc.

Let's suppose I take 2 sets of measurements over 2 path lengths.
Short 1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5
Long 10.1,10.2,10.3,10.4, 10.5
Two different SDs, but same accuracy/resolution

@Dirk: Are they different standard deviation?  What did you get when you calculated it?
